# apt-get does not always ask for confirmation

Tags: apt, software-installation

I have noticed that when installing software through `sudo apt-get install <packagename>` it does not always give me the:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Why is this so? I don't think that this has got anything to do with the size of the package as it has sometimes prompted me for a really small package, and then has not for a really large one.

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

```
apt:
  Installed: 1.0.9.2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.0.9.2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.9.2ubuntu2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```